# Как указать, какую часть формы печатать, в cxode?

Tags: xcode, macos, print

У меня на форме есть много разных элементов, но при нажатии cmd+p на печать попадает только тот элемент, на котором был фокус.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы не зависимо от того, на каком элементе фокус, я выводил на печать только нужную мне вьюху (NSView)?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл решение:

1) В h-файл добавил:

```
-(IBAction) print_card:(id) sender;
```

2) В m-файл добавил:

```
-(void)print_card:(id)sender {
      [[NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:[self get_active_view]] runOperation];
}
```

3) связал пункт меню Print... с этим экшеном в xib-файле.

PS. Фукнция get_active_view возвращает указатель на нужную мне вьюху. Можно вместо этого вставить сразу указатель на нужную вьюху.